# in rubymotion how to manually invoke table method

Tags: rubymotion

I'm using a UICollectionViewController and I'm trying to set an item as selected automatically (ie. previously selected options). If I attempt to set when I'm setting the cells data

```
def collectionView(view, cellForItemAtIndexPath: index_path)  

  //create the cell etc.. then
  cell.selected = true
  cell.update(index_path.row)
end
```

I get NoMethodError for selected. However this works from the normal select/deselect methods.

```
  def collectionView(view, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: index_path)
  cell = view.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index_path)
  cell.selected = true     
end
```

Any ideas on how can I automatically preselect a cell?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preselect a cell in a Collection View named `myColView`, call:

```
indexPath = NSIndexPath.indexPathForItem(1, inSection: 0)
myColView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: 0)
```

This method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called.